# Call function whenever selecting new pose bone

Tags: python, scripting, rigging

I'm working on a new rig and I would like to display the same property on multiple bones (like in maya). I'm unfortunately pretty stuck on scripting at the moment and would like to know how I can call a function whenever I select on or more bones and use that information to display the proper properties.